# How to handle the light(area)

Tags: light, snapping

[image]

Now I'm practicing the blender. There is problem when I handle the light

1. I want fit the plane light to the window, but I can't snap the light vertex. Is any other way to adjust the light to the window exactly?
2. When I scale up the light using addon(CAD transform), I can't resize the light. It just comes back to original size. What is the problem?

Comment: please be aware of the rule here, that you can only ask 1 question. Please open another question for your second question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select all 4 vertices of the window and press SHIFT-S -> Cursor to selection.

Then select your area light.

SHIFT-S -> Selection to cursor.

Then measure your height of the window with the measure tool.

[image]

Enter this size to size-y

[image]

Same for width + size-x